# Django from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

Tags: django, virtualenv, wsgi

An error POPs up that wsgi does not see django(when placing it on hosting). Although there is django in the virtual environment(I read that the path of the virtual environment can be incorrectly recognized, this is probably the problem, but it did not work out):

```
[Fri Apr 03 23:34:20 2020] [error] [client 5.18.99.123] from wsgi import application
[Fri Apr 03 23:34:20 2020] [error] [client 5.18.99.123] File "/home/users/m/marselabdullin/caparol_center_spb_decision/caparol_center_spb_decision/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Fri Apr 03 23:34:20 2020] [error] [client 5.18.99.123] from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Fri Apr 03 23:34:20 2020] [error] [client 5.18.99.123] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Code django.wsgi on hosting

```
import os, sys
virtual_env = os.path.expanduser('~/caparol_center_spb_decision/env')
home='~/caparol_center_spb_decision/env'
activate_this = os.path.join(virtual_env, 'bin/activate_this.py')
exec(open(activate_this).read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.expanduser('~/caparol_center_spb_decision/caparol_center_spb_decision'))
from wsgi import application
```